# How to set up recurring Retention Policies?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, information-management, retention

I need to set up a Retention Policy on a Document Library that sends an email out 12 months after the document was last modified, before sending an email out 15 months after a document was last modified, before deleting the document 15 months and 7 days after the document was last modified.

If the document is modified at any point in that process, the "timer" needs to start again, sending an email out 12 months after the last modified date and so on.

The problem I have is that the Retention Policy will not run again if the document is modified - by which I mean, if the document is modified after the 12 months email has been sent, the Retention Policy will not said another email in a further 12 months.

Additionally, if I try to set the Retention Policy to repeat, it does - but it doesn't seem to validate the condition again. If set to repeat after 12 months, the Retention Policy will run and send the email again after 12 months regardless of if it has been 12 months since the document was last modified.

Is there a solution to my problem?